# How to insert image into database?

Tags: php, mysql

I create CMS and I want to insert an image into a database. When I click a submit button a program inserts into the database title, content, but no image. Before during register, a program inserts into the database an image. I don't know why that doesn't know. I make probably any literal error, which I can't find.

```js
require_once('database.php');
 
class dodawanie extends database
{
    private $errors ='';
    private $img;
 
 public function get_image()
 {
     return $this->img;
 }
  
  public function set_image($img)
 {
     $this->img = $img;
 }
 public function insert()
 {
     $field1 = $this->get_title();
     $field2 = $this->get_content();
     $field3 = $this->get_image();
     $field4 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      
      
     if(empty($this->errors))
     {
     $sql = "INSERT INTO wiadomosci(`tytul`, `news`, `zdjecie`, `data_dodania`) VALUES('".$field1."', '".$field2."', '".$field3."', '".$field4."')";
      
     $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
         
     }
 }
 
 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $add = new dodawanie();
   $fault3 = $add->set_image($_POST['avatar']);
   echo $abc3 = $add->get_image();
   $inser = $add->insert();
```

Answer (score 0):

First to insert image in MySQL we have to create a table in data base.

Run the MYSQL command

```
CREATE TABLE `image` (
`image` LONGBLOB NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then if index.php contains the HTML form that allows users to choose the image file they want to upload, INSERT this therein

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert Image in MySql using PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$msg = '';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $img = file_get_contents($image);
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','admin') or die('Unable To connect');
    $sql = "insert into images (image) values(?)";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s",$img);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
    if($check==1){
        $msg = 'Image Successfullly UPloaded';
    }else{
        $msg = 'Error uploading image';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <button>Upload</button>
</form>
<?php
    echo $msg;
?>
</body>
</html>

save as index.php and run
```